# SOAP request error received: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag

Tags: soap

I am recieving the following error on sending a SOAP request.

SOAP request seems fine, in terms syntax and tags.

On looking and apparently there seem to be no syntax error, other similar requests have been success.

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 24 Jul 2023 12:58:39 GMT
Connection: close

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode><faultstring>WSDoAllReceiver: Error in converting to Document</faultstring><detail><Exception>org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: WSDoAllReceiver: Error in converting to Document
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processBasic(WSDoAllReceiver.java:157)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processMessage(WSDoAllReceiver.java:86)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllHandler.invoke(WSDoAllHandler.java:72)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:318)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:144)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1139)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Error in converting SOAP Envelope to Document
    at org.apache.rampart.util.Axis2Util.getDocumentFromSOAPEnvelope(Axis2Util.java:161)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processBasic(WSDoAllReceiver.java:154)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element &lt;soapenv:Envelope>
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [18,15]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:297)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:721)
    at org.apache.rampart.util.Axis2Util.getDocumentFromSOAPEnvelope(Axis2Util.java:151)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element &lt;soapenv:Envelope>
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [18,15]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:686)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2730)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1019)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:682)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:215)
    ... 30 more
</Exception></detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```